# how to pass repass an image file from $_FILES?

Tags: php, forms, file, hidden-field

I'm trying to make a two-step form on PHP. 
On the first step the form asks form some data and and an image. 
On the second step it asks for some more data and I repass the data from the first step through a input type hidden.

Is there a way to pass the image from the first step, like i do with the data in the hidden type input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one way to pass image from first step.
Start the session

```
session_start();
```

and store image name at

```
$_SESSION['my_image']=$_FILES['file_input_name']['tmp_name'];
```

instead repassing the file name at hidden input.